# how to get latest date column records when result should be filtered with unique column name in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have table as below:

[image]

I want write a sql query to get output as below:

[image]

the query should select all the records from the table but, when multiple records have same Id column value then it should take only one record having latest Date.
E.g., Here Rudolf id 1211 is present three times in input---in output only one Rudolf record having date 06-12-2010 is selected. same thing with James.

I tried to write a query but it was not succssful. So, please help me to form a query string in sql.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: BTW, most people here want table data as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the query you have tried. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I am using SQL Server Database

Comment: Also: I am pretty sure you can find a solution in the many answers tagged with [tag:greatest-n-per-group]

Comment: Can you post the SQL you tried? Even if it doesn't work, it helps us give more of a copy-and-paste answer if we the table and column names we use are the same as yours. It also lets us point out where you went wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can partition your data over `Date Desc` and get the first row of each partition

```
SELECT A.Id, A.Name, A.Place, A.Date FROM (
   SELECT 
     *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Date DESC) AS rn 
   FROM [Table]
) A WHERE A.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use  WITH TIES

```
    select top 1 PERCENT WITH TIES * from t
    order by (row_number() over(partition by id order by date desc))
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=280b7412b5c0c04c208f2914b44c7ce3

Answer (score 0):

As i can see from your example, duplicate rows differ only in Date. If it's a case, then simple `GROUP BY` with `MAX` aggregate function will do the job for you.

```
SELECT Id, Name, Place, MAX(Date) 
FROM [TABLE_NAME]
GROUP BY Id, Name, Place
```

Here is working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7025e/2